# Why GPU scaling (speedup) is usually worse than CPU scaling?

Tags: parallel-computing, gpu

Let's define scaling, as how linear the speedup of using more than one GPU or CPU is. For example, having 2 GPUs gives you 2x faster execution time.

I have noticed that in many software (e.g. Molecular Dynamics, Gromacs, AMBER, OPENMM), it scales very badly for more than 2 GPUs, but it is not a problem for CPUs (you can use hundreds of CPUs, even located on different nodes). What is stopping GPUs from achieving the same scaling as CPUs? Why CPUs even located physically far away with huge latency, can achieve better scaling than GPUs?

Comment: If you look at an MD software (HOOMD-blue) designed for GPUs from the very start, the observation does not seem to apply. Jens Glaser, et. al. "Strong scaling of general-purpose molecular dynamics simulations on GPUs," *Computer Physics Communications* **192** (2015): 97-107: " *We show that strong scaling speed-ups in excess of 50x are attainable on the Titan supercomputer, and weak scaling holds over three orders of magnitude in system size.* "

Comment: You might also be interested in the molecular-dynamics, high-performance-computing, and graphical-processing-units tags at [MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/). There's also specific tags for AMBER and Gromacs there! Finally, please come and say "hello" in the [Gromacs chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120383/gromacs) so that we remember that you're interested in Gromcas!

Comment: You might have additional communication channels. Have to move memory from GPU to RAM through network to RAM and then GPU versus just RAM-network-RAM. This gets more challenging if the GPUs are contending for link bandwidth. Just a hypothesis.

Comment: Too much missing information in this question. You "have noticed" on what platform? How are your "more than 2 GPUs" arranged? On a single node? In that case you probably have a bandwidth problem.

Comment: Too many unknowns in the question (as pointed out above) to answer this fully. One thing worth noticing is that a shiny new A100 will net you 10 TFLOPS DP, but a modern Intel Xeon will get you only ~0.05 TFLOPS (200x difference). At the same time, these compute units are paired with a (somewhat) similar amount of memory. So, for a similarly-sized problem, one spends less time computing on the GPU-based machine but a similar amount of time communicating (network).

Comment: @user20857 Where does the 0.05 TFLOPS number come from? From an [overview](https://www.microway.com/knowledge-center-articles/detailed-specifications-of-the-ice-lake-sp-intel-xeon-processor-scalable-family-cpus/) of "Ice Lake" Xeons: "With this new family of Xeon processors, Intel once again delivers unprecedented performance. Nearly every model provides over 1 TFLOPS (one teraflop of double-precision 64-bit performance per second), many models exceed 2 TFLOPS, and a few touch 3 TFLOPS.) " Based on clocks, core counts, and SIMD width that statement seems correct.